# How to permute arrays based on a predefined list of indexes

Tags: python-3.x

## Here are my few lines of code

```
import numpy as np

X = ([1,2,3], [2,4,5], [5,6,7])

y = ([2], [4], [5])

dist= np.random.RandomState(1)

r = dist.permutation(len(y))
```

Let's say

```
r= array([0, 2, 1])
```

Is there a way to permute the elements of X and y so that X and y elements are re-ordered according to indexes in r array i.e. y becomes `([2], [5], [1])` and X becomes `([1,2,3], [5,6,7], [2,4,5])` ?  I didn't find out the answer in python doc. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use comprehension with `zip`:

```
[i for _, i in sorted(zip(r, X])]
```

**EDIT**

When you `zip` this happens:

```
zip(r, X)
#((0, [1,2,3]), (2, [2,4,5]), (1, [5,6,7]))
```

Then you use `sorted()` this happens:

```
sorted(zip(r, X])
((0, [1,2,3]), (1, [5,6,7]), (2, [2,4,5]))
```

When you take only second element from `zip`ed and `sorted` you get this:

```
([1,2,3], [5,6,7], [2,4,5])
```

Comment: Thanks it works! could please just explain how that loops works

Comment: Thanks! is it the dash (_) in " i for _," that indicates you are only taking the second element ?

Comment: Dash contains value, but it's sort of practice

Comment: great! Just for me to understand this way of writing thoroughly. What could I have typed instead if I wanted to extract only the first element from the zip.

Comment: `[j for j, i in ...]` would do it